# developing facebook messenger chatbot

Tags: node.js, facebook, wit.ai

I am trying to develop Facebook messenger chat bot. I have set my messenger and node server to talk with each other but when i try to send a message from messenger,after it reaches node server it tries to do merge action using node-wit library that in terms gives an error.

> C:\Users\username\node_modules\node-wit\lib\wit.js:161
>           this.converse(
>               ^
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'converse' of undefined
>       at C:\Users\username\node_modules\node-wit\lib\wit.js:161:13
>       at Object.actions.say.merge (C:\Users\username\messenger.js:147:5)
>       at null. (C:\Users\username\node_modules\node-wit\lib\wit.js
>   :230:22)
>       at C:\Users\username\node_modules\node-wit\lib\wit.js:32:9
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)

here is my code:

```
 wit.runActions(
    sessionId, // the user's current session
    msg, // the user's message 
    sessions[sessionId].context, // the user's current session state
    (error, context) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log('Oops! Got an error from Wit:', error);
      } else {
        // Our bot did everything it has to do.
        // Now it's waiting for further messages to proceed.
        console.log('Waiting for futher messages.');



        // Updating the user's current session state
        sessions[sessionId].context = context;
      }
    }
  );
```

Comment: The reason you don't get an answer is because it's not possible to understand how your app works. Also your code snippet is 1:1 copied from a working tutorial. So your problem have to be at another position.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your node to version 6. It is a version related problem. Let me know if it works fine after upgrading.